# Using external cellphone backup battery as "UPS" for Pi?

Tags: battery, ups

I'm currently experimenting using an external power supply (for cellphones) as a type of "UPS" for my Pi.  It seems to work quite well.  Can anyone think of a reason why this isn't a good idea?
I got this:
  [http://www.amazon.com/PowerBot%C2%AE-Universal-External-MicroUSB-Stainless/dp/B00CV11X84/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00CV11X84)

I then connected the power cable from the Pi into the battery, and finally the 5v power supply into the battery to keep it charged.   So far, it's been working great.  I can pull the power supply from the wall, and the Pi stays running.  My goal is to simply have something in place to handle small/short power hits.

Thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: I do the same thing the only concern is some batteries do not allow charging while powering the Pi. There is even software that can improve on your solution http://raspi-ups.appspot.com/en/index.jsp,

Comment: Thanks for the info!   Didn't know about the software.  My Pi is wiFi, so the ethernet switch check probably wouldn't be very helpful.  But the software looks interesting.  I'll install that and see what it reports.  Curious how it would know how much power is remaining in the battery..

Comment: I am not sure it does I think what it does do is perform a graceful shutdown.

Comment: I built a garage door opener out of my Pi, using a relay board connected to the GPIO port.  So now I can open my garage door with my mobile device.  Works great!  However, occasionally I've seen the Pi get stuck on the 'maintenance screen' after a power hit.   Ideally, I'd like to find a way to have it automatically recover from that on its own.  But the UPS seemed like a good idea, too.

Comment: The current capabilities of this particular device {PowerBot® TNT PB2611 2600mAh Universal Power Bank External Back Up Battery + Built-In USB Port Output} is only 500/800mA in/out - so whilst it may keep a RPi A+/B+ operating I do wonder whether there is enough for the more current hungry RPis. The fact that you have been able to put it "in series" with the power supply to your RPi does suggest that it can supply the load (your RPI) but I'd be very surprised if it charged itself whilst doing so.  Also any devices attached to the RPI will also draw on the total power available...!